# Mapping a large JSON with Restkit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I am using restkit for a time now. And everything worked perfect. But now I want to map a json into my core database. This is a JSON of (10 MB). You can see the JSON over [here](http://apps.appmax.be/claes/items.json).

I have an API class where I do my mapping

```
-(RKObjectManager *)mapGetItems{
    RKEntityMapping* rubriekMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    rubriekMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"itemNum"] ;
    [rubriekMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"ItemNum": @"itemNum",
     @"ItemDescNl": @"itemDescNl",
     @"ItemDescFr": @"itemDescFr",
     @"Group1": @"group1",
     @"Group2": @"group2",
     @"Group3": @"group3",
     @"Group4": @"group4",
     @"DateCr": @"dateCr",
     @"GrpItem": @"grpItem",
     @"GrpDesc1": @"grpDesc1",
     @"GrpDesc2": @"grpDesc2",
     @"GrpDesc1Fr": @"grpDesc1Fr",
     @"SalUnitNl": @"salUnitNl",
     @"SalUnitFr": @"salUnitFr",
     @"LadderQty": @"ladderQty",
     @"Netprice": @"netPrice",
     @"IsPromo": @"isPromo",
     @"IsNew": @"isNew",
     }];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:rubriekMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:@"ds-ttitems.tt-items"                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

    NSArray *arrResponsDescriptor = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:responseDescriptor, nil];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:arrResponsDescriptor];

    return objectManager;

}
```

And a dataModel class, in this class I setup my object store. 
This is all going well and everything is set up correctly. 
Now for my request I do this.

```
-(void)fetchRubrieken{
    API *api = [API new];
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[ClaesDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [api mapGetItems];
    NSString *request = @"/claes/items.json";

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:request parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                NSError *error = nil;
                                BOOL success = [store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext  save:&error];
                                if (!success) RKLogWarning(@"Failed saving managed object context: %@", error);
                                NSLog(@"done fetching");

                            }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                               delegate:nil
                                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [alert show];
                                NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                            }];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [context save:&error];
}
```

The problem is not that it isn't working. It only takes a very very long time. So my question is, how can i make this go faster?

Hope that anybody can help me!

Kind regards,

PS. If you need more details, I will provide but I think this is the essential part.

Comment: Reduce the JSON size, do you need the whole thing on a mobile device? You may want to download the file yourself, split it into parts and then get RestKit to do the mapping for each part (so the parts run concurrently)...

Comment: It's a whole catalog of products. And I need it all in one time because the first screen should be an overview of all the products..

Comment: And there's no way to request the overview and then details for the selected item? (Or it's for offline use?)

Comment: That is only the overview... And yes it's for offline use. Is 10MB so many data for a JSON on mobile devices ?

Comment: Depends if you're going to have it all loaded in memory at once. Generally you should try to have as little data loaded as possible.

Comment: Okay I am going to try to make the JSON a lot smaller. Thanks for the help!